# Codeigniter form custom validation not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a function to the from validation but is not working the validation is done  and doesn't use the function `checkPostalCode`

```
 public function build()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'field' => 'postal_code',
                'name' => 'Postal Code',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|exact_length[5],callback_checkPostalCode',
                'errors' => array(
                    'required' =>  trans('form.errors.required'),
                    'numeric' => trans('form.errors.numeric'),
                    'exact_length' => trans('form.errors.exact_length', array('%length%' => 5)),
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public function checkPostalCode($pc){
        if($pc == "08000")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

The validation done on checkPostalCode is not working

Comment: which 'postal_code' value is not going to the validation function ? give me an example

Comment: How would that ever be able to pass validation? You have `exact_length[5]` but in your function, you only return true if it's `08` (two characters)? Wouldn't that mean that if `exact_length[5]` passes, your validation would not?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|exact_length[5]|callback_checkPostalCode',
```

instead of

```
'rules' => 'trim|required|numeric|exact_length[5],callback_checkPostalCode',
```

Comment: yes it's correct I have to use `I` instead `,`, but  the validation always is  false

Comment: @afsdi3 - Read my comment under your question and you'll find out why it always returns false. You are validating it using two competing criteria. For it to pass, the string would need to be 5 characters long _and_ be equal to "08" (which is 2 characters) all at the same time. That's an impossible validation.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , I know,this is fixed, but I have the always false problem even if I use `public function checkPostalCode($pc){ return true; }`

Comment: @afsdi3 - You need to update your code to reflect that. We can only help you with what you show us. You should also output the value you're trying to validate. Is it 5 characters? Is it numeric?